# MySQL Join missing results

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to select all users and get the amount of hours each user has logged from the joined times table. However, if the user has no times logged at all, I am not getting their name returned in the results. I would still like to get the name of every user, even if they have nothing logged in the times table.

I can get the results for all users if I remove the line:

```
AND (times.time_date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2014-03-31')
```

Here is my full query, What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT users.user_id,
users.user_name,
SUM(times.time_used) as hours
FROM users
LEFT JOIN times on users.user_id = times.user_id
WHERE users.user_reminder = 1
AND users.status_id = 1
AND (times.time_date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2014-03-31')
GROUP BY users.user_id
ORDER BY users.user_name
```

Comment: what have you stored in db if the user has no logged in time

Comment: Thanks. I tried that already, it didn’t work. M Khalid Junaid has the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `AND`  clause in `ON()` clause, using AND filter after WHERE clause will filter out the whole resultset,so if any user whose status_id is one and user_reminder is one but no time entries will be filtered,but if using AND in your on clause will join the users specific to the conditions and will return the uesrs even if they have no time entries

```
SELECT users.user_id,
users.user_name,
SUM(times.time_used) as hours
FROM users
LEFT JOIN times on (users.user_id = times.user_id
AND (times.time_date BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2014-03-31') )
WHERE users.user_reminder = 1
AND users.status_id = 1
GROUP BY users.user_id
ORDER BY users.user_name
```

Comment: That is brilliant, I didn’t realise the on clause could contain an and clause. This now does what I need it to.  Thanks for the explanation.